# Force service to return json instead of default html

Tags: php, curl

I want to be able to code in php the equivalent to this curl command:

```
curl -F out=json --form-string 'content=<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>check it</title></head><body></body></html>' http://validator.w3.org/nu/
```

This curl command returns json as expected.
Maybe I am missing something from their documentation here:
https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service:-Input:-POST-body and https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service%3A-HTTP-interface

The problem that I have now is that the web service returns html instead of json.
Although I am setting the header accept to json it does not work. I also tried to set both accept and Content-Type but this triggers an error from the web service saying non valid input. Here is the code that I need your help with:

```
$html = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>test</title></head><body></body></html>";
$endPoint = "http://validator.w3.org/nu/";
$timeout = 5000;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endPoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Accept: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('content' => $html, 'out' => 'json'));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);    
error_log(__FILE__. ": " . __LINE__ . ": " . var_export($output, true));
echo $output;
```

After reading Ignacio question I am updating with this information from w3c documentation page:

In their documentation they say the html string should be sent in http body and in their java library they are using this:

```
String response = null;
String source = "your html here";
HttpResponse<String> uniResponse = Unirest.post("http://localhost:8080/vnu")
    .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36")
    .header("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8")
    .queryString("out", "gnu")
    .body(source)
    .asString();
response = uniResponse.getBody();
```

Could this be a hint for you? Just to let you know I tried both

```
http://validator.w3.org/nu/?out=json
```

and

```
http://validator.w3.org/nu/
```

endpoints (as value of $endPoint variable in php script above).

Comment: Postfields are only being sent if the request method is POST. You are using GET right now.

Comment: @Charlottte, You are right. Added post method but still getting html. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the web service can return JSON? Are you sure that the service will return JSON if you set that header?

Comment: @Ignacio, When I run that curl command it returns json. So I guess there is something wrong with my PHP code. I tried running the php code from both browser and command line and in both cases I get html. I added the links w3c validation service API.

Comment: Have you checked that `content` is the last field to be sent? Also, the service doesn't seem to care about the `Accept:` header at all.

Comment: @Ignacio, you brought a very good point. I updated the question maybe this gonna lead us to a solution.

Comment: Their Java library is using the [POST body](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Service%3A-Input%3A-POST-body) method, which is different from the one you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result that you are looking for, you have to send your data as `multipart/form-data` (you can take a look on the [validator page](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) or the request sent by curl to see that data is sent as `multipart/form-data` ), for that take this example :

```
$url = 'http://validator.w3.org/nu/';
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>test</title></head><body></body></html>';

$boundary = 'your-boundary'; 

$body = '--' . $boundary . "\r\n";
// set the "out" as "json"
$body .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="out"' . "\r\n" . "\r\n";
$body .= 'json' . "\r\n";
$body .= "--" . $boundary ."\r\n";
// set the "content"
$body .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="content"' . "\r\n" . "\r\n";
$body .= $html . "\r\n";
$body .= "--" . $boundary . "--" . "\r\n" . "\r\n";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary='.$boundary));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);

echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Then you'll get something like this :

```
{
    "messages": [{
            "type": "info",
            "message": "The Content-Type was “text/html”. Using the HTML parser."
        }, {
            "type": "info",
            "message": "Using the schema for HTML with SVG 1.1, MathML 3.0, RDFa 1.1, and ITS 2.0 support."
        }],
    "source": {
        "type": "text/html",
        "encoding": "utf-8",
        "code": "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>test</title></head><body></body></html>"
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.